# If $A$ is symmetric show that $(BA^{-1})^T(A^{-1}B^T)^{-1}=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is symmetric show that $(BA^{-1})^T(A^{-1}B^T)^{-1}=I$

I can see that:

$$
(BA^{-1})^T(A^{-1}B^T)^{-1}\\
(A^{-1})^TB^T(B^T)^{-1}(A^{-1})^{-1}\\
A^{-1}B^T(B^T)^{-1}A\\
...\\
A^{-1}...A=I
$$

I assume I would arrive at the last step, but I am confused how to get there.

Comment: transposition and inversion are commutative on matrices...

Comment: $B^T$ is sitting right there next to its inverse, just cancel it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use

$$ (X^T)^{-1}=(X^{-1})^T, \quad (XY)^T=Y^TX^T, \quad (XY)^{-1}=Y^{-1}X^{-1}$$

for all quadratic matrices $X,Y$ (with existing inverse). Didn't you use these equations above?

$$ (BA^{-1})^T(A^{-1}B^T)^{-1}=((A^{-1})^TB^T)((B^T)^{-1}(A^{-1})^{-1})\\
=(A^{-1})^T(B^T(B^T)^{-1})A\\
=(A^{-1})^TA\\
=(A^{-1})^TA^T \\
=I
$$

In the fourth equation you need, that $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: You don't actually need the first fact. What do you mean by quadratic in the context of a matrix?

Comment: @Ben I think quadratic = square